# How can i select multiple columns from a subquery instead of multiple similar subqueries?

Tags: sql, django, join, subquery

I'm trying to sort a list of images by views/downloads. I'm storing the statistics in a different table where I save a row for each day. After a few days of searching I have managed to get a working SQL but it doesn't seem very efficient since I'm doing almost the same query 3 times. Here are my tables and SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "images_stats" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "image_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "images_image" ("id"),
    "date" date NOT NULL,
    "view_count" integer unsigned NOT NULL,
    "download_count" integer unsigned NOT NULL
)

images_list = Images.objects.raw('''
    SELECT *, 
        (SELECT 1.0*SUM(s.view_count)/SUM(s.download_count) 
         FROM images_stats AS s
         WHERE s.image_id = w.id AND s.date < %s AND s.date >= %s) AS ratio,
        (SELECT 1.0*SUM(s.view_count)/SUM(s.download_count) 
         FROM images_stats AS s
         WHERE s.image_id = w.id AND s.date < %s) AS global_ratio,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)==0
         FROM images_stats AS s
         WHERE s.image_id = w.id AND s.date < %s) AS count
    FROM images_image as w
    WHERE w.category_id = %s
    ORDER BY count, ratio, global_ratio
''', [date.today(), date.today()-timedelta(days=1), date.today(), date.today(), category.id])
```

Does anybody know how i can optimize this SQL? I have some SQL knowledge but apparently not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *, 
    SUM(case when s.date < %s AND s.date >= %s then s.view_count else 0 end)/
    SUM(case when s.date < %s AND s.date >= %s then s.download_count else 0 end) 
        AS ratio,
    SUM(case when s.date < %s then s.view_count else 0 end)/
    SUM(case when s.date < %s then s.download_count else 0 end) 
        AS global_ratio,
    COUNT(*)==0 AS count
FROM images_image as w
LEFT JOIN images_stats AS s 
    ON s.image_id = w.id
WHERE w.category_id = %s
GROUP BY w.id
ORDER BY count, ratio, global_ratio
```

Comment: That looks clean however it does not work. I get ratio: none as well as global_ratio:none. I've just realized my code doesn't work also as i get duplicate images, i even tried adding group by but wont help.